# Backing to slider-handle in top / jQuery UI slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a jQuery UI slider implemented on my site. The slider has 600px height, and it's a vertical slider. When I click on a slider background and I don't see a slider-handler, the page is coming back to the top of the slider-handler. I don't know how to disable this function. I don't want to go back to the top after a click.

Can anyone help?

HTML:

```
<div id="first-slider1"></div>
```

JS (all MVC model):

```
    var slider1  = new Slider('first-slider1','vertical',false,false,0,1,1,1,1,700);
    function Slider(name,orientation,range,disabled,min,max,value,zmiana,zmieniona,animate) {
    this.name = name;
    this.orientation = orientation;
    this.range = range;
    this.disabled = disabled;
    this.min = min;
    this.max = max;
    this.value = value;
    this.zmiana = zmiana;
    this.zmieniona = zmieniona;
    this.animate = animate
    }
```

CSS

```
first-slider1 {
    margin-top: 40px;
        width: 18px;
        height: 589px;
        background: url('../img/suwak-tlo.jpg') no-repeat !important;
        border: none;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 10%;
    }
```

Comment: Can you post some of your HTMl and JS or JQ code?